# How many steps on $S_n$ are required to span $V\wedge V$, $V = K^n$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, permutations, permutation-groups

Let $A$ be a set of generators of $G=S_n$; assume $e\in A$,
$A=A^{-1}$. Let $V = K^n$, $K$ a field. Consider the natural
action of $G$ on $V$ (namely, $g(e_i) = e_{g(i)}$) and on $W = V\wedge V$
(namely, $g(e_i \wedge e_j) = e_{g(i)}\wedge e_{g(j)}$). Must there be a $w\in
W$ such that the vector space spanned by $A^k w$ equals $W$ for some
$k = o(n^2)$? What about for some $k = O(n^{3/2})$, or for $k = O(n
\log n)$?

A note which may help see the question as non-trivial: the fact that, for $k=o(n^2)$, the set $A^k$ need not act transitively on pairs of distinct elements of $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ (see [How many steps are required for double transitivity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349391/how-many-steps-are-required-for-double-transitivity/349678#349678)) shows that we cannot always
choose $w$ of the form $e_i\wedge e_j$.